# Capture frame from ip cam using opencv

Tags: opencv, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to connect cp plus ip camera to my app by using open cv. I tried so much ways to capture the frame. help me to capture frame using "rtsp" protocol. URL of the IP cam is "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.108:554/VideoInput/1/mpeg4/1 ". i tried this using VLC player. its working. if there is way to capture frame by libvlc and pass into open CV please mentioned the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.108:554/VideoInput/1/mpeg4/1?.mjpg" opencv looks end of url for video stream type.

Comment: I tried your way. still won't work. i used VideoCapture for capture the camera.

Comment: I can sudgest only two alternatives: 1) use .mp4 or .mpeg instead .mjpeg 2) rebuild opencv with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the URL that gives you the camera's jpg snapshot.
See here for details on how to find it using onvif:

http://me-ol-blog.blogspot.co.il/2017/07/getting-still-image-urluri-of-ipcam-or.html

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to discovery your rtsp url, and test it at the vlc. You said that you already have that.

If someone need to discovery the rtsp url, I recommend the software onvif-device-tool ([link](https://www.lingodigit.com/onvif_nvc.html)) or the gsoap-onvif ([link](https://github.com/tonyhu/gsoap-onvif)), both works on Linux, look at your terminal, the rtsp url will be there. After discovery the rtsp url I recommend to test it on vlc player ([link](http://www.videolan.org/)), you can test using the menu option "opening network stream" or from command line:

```
vlc rtsp://your_url
```

If you already have the rtsp url and the tested it successfully at vlc, than  create a cv::VideoCapture and grab the frames. You can do that like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture stream = cv::VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.108:554/VideoInput/1/mpeg4/1");
    if (!stream.isOpened()) return -1; // if not success, exit program

    double width = stream.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double height = stream.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video
    std::cout << "Frame size : " << width << " x " << height << std::endl;

    cv::namedWindow("Onvif",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Onvif"
    cv::Mat frame;

    while (1) {
        // read a new frame from video
        if (!stream.read(frame)) { //if not success, break loop
            std::cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey(30); continue;
        }
        cv::imshow("Onvif", frame); //show the frame in "Onvif" window

        if (cv::waitKey(15)==27) //wait for 'esc'
            break;
    }
}
```

To compile:

```
 g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```